# Count (Distinct ([value)) OVER (Partition by) in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, window-functions

I have written this and successfully executed in Oracle

```
COUNT (DISTINCT APEC.COURSE_CODE) OVER (
                                            PARTITION BY s.REGISTRATION_NUMBER
                                            ,APEC.APE_ID
                                            ,COV.ACADEMIC_SESSION
                                            ) APE_COURSES_PER_ACADEMIC_YEAR
```

I'm trying to achieve the same result in SQL Server (our source database uses Oracle but our warehouse uses SQL Server).

I know the distinct isn't supported with window functions in SQL Server 2008 - can anyone suggest an alternative?

Comment: On the dba site [Can you use COUNT DISTINCT with an OVER clause?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/76761/3690)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Partition Function COUNT() OVER possible using DISTINCT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11202878/partition-function-count-over-possible-using-distinct)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's what I recently came across. I got it from this [post](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1455129-391-1.aspx). So far it works really well for me.

```
DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY PartitionByFields ORDER BY OrderByFields ASC) +
DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY PartitionByFields ORDER BY OrderByFields DESC) - 1 AS DistinctCount
```

Comment: GREAT, Thank you!

Comment: This includes `NULL` values, whereas `COUNT()` doesn't.

Answer (score 9):

Alas, you cannot do `count(distinct) over` in SQL Server.  You can do this with a subquery.  The idea is to enumerate the values within each course code (and subject to the other partitioning conditions).  Then, just count up the values where the sequence number is 1:

```
select sum(case when cc_seqnum = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as APE_COURSES_PER_ACADEMIC_YEAR
from (select . . . ,
             row_number () OVER (PARTITION BY s.REGISTRATION_NUMBER, APEC.APE_ID,
                                              COV.ACADEMIC_SESSION,
                                              APEC.COURSE_CODE
                                 ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)
                                ) as cc_seqnum
      from . . . 
     ) t
```

You have a complex query.  I would suggest that you replace the `count(distinct)` with the `row_number()` and make your current query a subquery or CTE for the final query.