# TotalCount based on column that still needs to be fetched

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given the fetched row below I need to also total how may **id-token** pair has a **valuableField**. The value in `valuableField` may have duplicates

the field

`id`    - column of table

`token` - column of table

`valuableField` - column of table

**How do I do the `totalCountOfValuableFIeld` field?**

`totalCountOfValuableField` - not a column in a table and is the total count of distinct `valuableField per id-token pair.

I tried this query but it forces me to group the rows but that is not what I want.

```
select id, token, valuableField, count(distinct valuableField) from table_1
```

**Sample Data**

Current Table

```
╔════════╦═════════════╦═══════════════╗
║ id     ║ token       ║ valuableField ║ 
╠════════╬═════════════╬═══════════════╣
║     88 ║ test        ║ unique1       ║
║     88 ║ test        ║ duplicate1    ║
║     88 ║ random1     ║ 1unique       ║
║     88 ║ test        ║ duplicate1    ║
║     76 ║ bar         ║ 1unique       ║
║     76 ║ bar         ║ 2unique       ║
╚════════╩═════════════╩═══════════════╝
```

What I want

```
╔════════╦═════════════╦═══════════════╦════════════════════════════╗
║ id     ║ token       ║ valuableField ║ totalCountOfValuableField  ║ 
╠════════╬═════════════╬═══════════════╬════════════════════════════╣
║     88 ║ test        ║ unique1       ║            2               ║
║     88 ║ test        ║ duplicate1    ║            2               ║
║     88 ║ random1     ║ 1unique       ║            1               ║
║     88 ║ test        ║ duplicate1    ║            2               ║
║     76 ║ bar         ║ 2unique       ║            2               ║
║     76 ║ bar         ║ 3unique       ║            2               ║
╚════════╩═════════════╩═══════════════╩════════════════════════════╝
```

Comment: On a sidenote: You should not call a column `id` when it's not the table's ID. An ID is supposed to uniquely identify a record in the table. Yours does not.

Comment: Why does the row with `unique1` have a count of `2`? The value `unique1` only appears once in your sample data

Comment: **88-test** pair has two unique `valuableField` (unique1 and duplicate1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your expected results it seems you want to count distinct `valuableField` per `id` and `token`. <strike>You'd do this with `COUNT DISTINCT OVER`:</strike>

```
select
  id,
  token,
  valuableField,
  count(distinct valuableField) over (partition by id, token) as total
from mytable;
```

**UPDATE:** As has been mentioned, PostgreSQL doesn't support DISTINCT in window functions. So you must use a subquery instead:

```
select
  id,
  token,
  valuableField,
  (
    select count(distinct m2.valuableField)
    from mytable m2
    where m2.id = m1.id and m2.token = m1.token
  ) as total 
from mytable m1;
```

This, however is not "how may id-token pair has a valuableField". If you wanted that, you'd have to partition by `valuableField` and count the distinct `id`/`token` pairs.

Comment: Unfortunately Postgres does not allow `distinct` in a window function

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Oh, how disappointing. I knew that SQL Server doesn't, but then that's just SQL Server. But PostgreSQL? They are usually so good.

Comment: I agree, that is disappointing. If I recall correctly there will be some enhancements to window functions for Postgres 11 - but I don't know if that includes the support for `distinct`

Comment: thanks you guys. I've accepted this one as this came in first than @horse answer, but upvoted you two as your answers help me. Did this sub query approach and works. Just to add, if token is nullable, one should use `is not distinct from`.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately Postgres does not (yet) support `distinct` in a [window function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-window.html). Based on the [workaround for SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27566842/330315), you can do the following:

```
select id, 
       token, 
       valuableField, 
       count(*) filter (where rn = 1) over (partition by id, token) 
from (
  select id, token, valuableField, 
         row_number() over (partition by id, token, valuableField) as rn
  from table_1
) t
```