# Distinct with Aggregation and Analytical functions

Tags: postgresql, distinct, window-functions

I'm just curious, is there a way to do this in Postgres?

```
SUM(DISTINCT column_a) OVER(PARTITION BY column_b, column_c)
```

Using DISTINCT causes an error: DISTINCT is not implemented for window functions

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27566842/330315

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT column_a,
       column_b,
       column_c,
       sum(column_a) FILTER (WHERE is_new) OVER w
FROM (SELECT column_a,
             column_b,
             column_c,
             column_a IS DISTINCT FROM lag(column_a) OVER w AS is_new
      FROM atable
      WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY column_b, column_c ORDER BY column_a)
     ) AS q
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY column_b, column_c ORDER BY column_a);
```

In the inner query, all duplicates of `column_a` will get `is_new = FALSE`, so these duplicates are not counted in the outer query.

Comment: WOW!, thanks for the help. Seems to be working as expected.