# How can I prevent SQL Server from squaring the number of rows scanned?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm running a query over a table variable that holds 22 227 rows. The query used to take 2-3 seconds to complete (which I still think is too slow) but since I added another field to the `ORDER BY` clause in `DENSE_RANK()` it now completes in 4.5 minutes!

If I include `[t2].[aisdt]` with or without `[t2].[aiID]`, the execution plan shows that it's scanning 494 039 529 rows, which is 22 227 squared. The following query generates the correct results, just much too slowly to be useful.

```
SELECT MAX([t].[SetNum]) OVER (PARTITION BY NULL) AS [MaxSet]
      ,*
FROM (
    SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY [t2].[aisdt], [t2].[aiID]) AS [SetNum]
          ,[t2].*
    FROM (
        SELECT [aiID]
              ,COUNT(DISTINCT [acID]) AS [noac]
        FROM @Temp
        GROUP BY [aiID]
    ) [t1]
    JOIN @Temp [t2]
      ON [t2].[aiID] = [t1].[aiID]
    WHERE [t1].[noac] < [t2].[asm]
) [t]
```

Just to be clear, the culprit is the bold section in "DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY **[t2].[aisdt]**, [t2].[aiID])". Removing this field (which needs to remain) drops the execution time back down to 2-3 seconds. I think it might have something to do with `JOIN`ing the table to itself on `[aiID]` but not `[aisdt]`.

How can I speed this query up to complete in the same time as before, or less?

---

#### EDIT

Table definition:

```
DECLARE @Temp TABLE (
    [aiID] INT NOT NULL INDEX [IX_Temp_aiID] -- not unique
    ,[aisdt] DATETIME NOT NULL INDEX [IX_Temp_aisdt] -- not unique
    ,[asm] INT NOT NULL
    ,[cpcID] INT NULL
    ,[cpce] VARCHAR(10) NULL
    ,[acID] INT NULL
    ,[ctvID] INT NULL
    ,[ct] VARCHAR(100) NULL
    ,[_36_other_non_matched_fields_] VARCHAR(MAX)

    ,UNIQUE ([aiID], [cpcID], [cpce], [acID], [ctvID], [ct])
)
```

`[aisdt]` is unique per `[aiID]`, but there can be multiple `[aiID]`s with the same `[aisdt]`.

```
INSERT INTO @TEMP
VALUES (64, '2017-03-23 10:00:00', 1, 17, '', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'blah')
      ,(64, '2017-03-23 10:00:00', 1, 34, '', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'blah')
      ,(99, '2017-04-08 09:00:00', 1, 25, 'Y', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'blah')
      ,(99, '2017-04-08 09:00:00', 1, 16, 'Y', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'blah')
      ,(99, '2017-04-08 09:00:00', 1, 76, 'Y', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'blah')
      ,(99, '2017-04-08 09:00:00', 1, 82, 'Y', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'blah')
      ,(42, '2017-04-14 16:00:00', 2, 32, '', 32, NULL, NULL, 'blah')
      ,(42, '2017-04-14 16:00:00', 2, 32, '', 47, NULL, NULL, 'blah')
      ,(42, '2017-04-14 16:00:00', 2, 47, '', 32, NULL, NULL, 'blah')
      ,(42, '2017-04-14 16:00:00', 2, 47, '', 47, NULL, NULL, 'blah')
      ,(54, '2017-03-23 10:00:00', 1, 17, '', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'blah')
      ,(54, '2017-03-23 10:00:00', 1, 34, '', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'blah')
      ,(89, '2017-04-08 09:00:00', 1, 25, 'Y', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'blah')
      ,(89, '2017-04-08 09:00:00', 1, 16, 'Y', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'blah')
      ,(89, '2017-04-08 09:00:00', 1, 76, 'Y', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'blah')
      ,(89, '2017-04-08 09:00:00', 1, 82, 'Y', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'blah')
      ,(32, '2017-04-14 16:00:00', 3, 32, '', 32, NULL, NULL, 'blah')
      ,(32, '2017-04-14 16:00:00', 3, 32, '', 47, NULL, NULL, 'blah')
      ,(32, '2017-04-14 16:00:00', 3, 47, '', 32, NULL, NULL, 'blah')
      ,(32, '2017-04-14 16:00:00', 3, 47, '', 47, NULL, NULL, 'blah')
```

It must be sorted by `[aisdt]` (datetime) first, then `[aiID]`, then numbered into sets based on `[aiID]`.

I want to see:

```
5, 1, 54, '2017-03-23 10:00:00', 1, 17, '', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'blah'
5, 1, 54, '2017-03-23 10:00:00', 1, 34, '', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'blah'
5, 2, 64, '2017-03-23 10:00:00', 1, 17, '', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'blah'
5, 2, 64, '2017-03-23 10:00:00', 1, 34, '', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'blah'
5, 3, 89, '2017-04-08 09:00:00', 1, 25, 'Y', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'blah'
5, 3, 89, '2017-04-08 09:00:00', 1, 16, 'Y', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'blah'
5, 3, 89, '2017-04-08 09:00:00', 1, 76, 'Y', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'blah'
5, 3, 89, '2017-04-08 09:00:00', 1, 82, 'Y', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'blah'
5, 4, 99, '2017-04-08 09:00:00', 1, 25, 'Y', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'blah'
5, 4, 99, '2017-04-08 09:00:00', 1, 16, 'Y', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'blah'
5, 4, 99, '2017-04-08 09:00:00', 1, 76, 'Y', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'blah'
5, 4, 99, '2017-04-08 09:00:00', 1, 82, 'Y', NULL, NULL, NULL, 'blah'
5, 5, 32, '2017-04-14 16:00:00', 3, 32, '', 32, NULL, NULL, 'blah'
5, 5, 32, '2017-04-14 16:00:00', 3, 32, '', 47, NULL, NULL, 'blah'
5, 5, 32, '2017-04-14 16:00:00', 3, 47, '', 32, NULL, NULL, 'blah'
5, 5, 32, '2017-04-14 16:00:00', 3, 47, '', 47, NULL, NULL, 'blah'
```

Comment: @MartinSmith 2008

Comment: Could you post create table scripts and some sample data?

Comment: Have you added any indexes to the table variable? e.g `DECLARE @Temp TABLE([aisdt] int, [aiID] int, [acID] int, [asm] int, PRIMARY KEY([aiID], [asm]))`? (you may need to add other key columns to the end until you get to a combination that is expected to be unique)

Comment: @MartinSmith Yes, both fields in the `DENSE_RANK()` have indices, and I tried putting an index on both of them together, but that didn't help by much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main idea is taken from [Partition Function COUNT() OVER possible using DISTINCT](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11202878/4116017) that @Jayvee pointed out with a small addition that would make it work when `acID` has `NULL` values.

Most likely you can remove all indexes from your `@Temp` table, the server will have to sort it in several different ways for different window functions anyway, but there is no self-join, so it should be faster.

The plan will have many sorts and they also can be slow, especially when engine underestimates the number of rows in a table. And table variable is exactly this case. Optimiser thinks that table variable has only 1 row. So, I'd recommend to use a classic `#Temp` table here, even without indexes.

An index on `(aiID, acID)` should help, but there will be other sorts any way.

```
WITH
CTE_Counts
AS
(
    SELECT
        *
        -- use DENSE_RANK() to calculate COUNT(DISTINCT)
        , DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [aiID] ORDER BY [acID])
        + DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [aiID] ORDER BY [acID] DESC)
        -- subtract extra 1 if acID has NULL values within the partition
        - MAX(CASE WHEN [acID] IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY [aiID])
        - 1 AS [noac]
    FROM @Temp
)
,CTE_SetNum
AS
(
    SELECT
        *
        , DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY [aisdt], [aiID]) AS [SetNum]
    FROM CTE_Counts
    WHERE [noac] < [asm]
)
SELECT
    *
    , MAX([SetNum]) OVER () AS [MaxSet]
FROM CTE_SetNum
ORDER BY
    [aisdt]
    ,[aiID]
    ,[SetNum]
;
```

Comment: This should work too, also nice enhancement to the dense_rank trick, +1

Comment: Thank you! That's brilliant! Yes, the indices are not necessary (they only saved half a second before anyway).

Answer (score 1):

Index as suggested in the comments would definitely play a major part but also I think you can re-write the query without self join in this way:

```
   SELECT MAX([t].[SetNum]) OVER (PARTITION BY NULL) AS [MaxSet]
      ,*
FROM (
    SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY [t1].[aisdt], [t1].[aiID]) AS [SetNum]
          ,[t1].*
    FROM (
        SELECT * ,dense_rank() over(partition by aiID order by [acID]) - 
        dense_rank() over(partition by aiID order by [acID]) - 1 AS [noac]
        FROM @Temp
    ) [t1]
    WHERE [t1].[noac] < [t1].[asm]
) [t]
```

Comment: You can't use count distinct over - not valid

Comment: Thanks @t-clausen.dk , I have updated to use dense_rank as count distinct based on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11202878/partition-function-count-over-possible-using-distinct

Comment: Your query is nice and fast (a fraction of a second) but it produces far too many results (yours: 16 427 sets compared to mine: 12 338 sets). You must have removed some of my filtering, but I haven't analysed your query yet to see what's logically different.

Comment: Thanks for a link to the question that discusses calculating `COUNT(DISTINCT)` using `DENSE_RANK`. Very clever.

Comment: I just noticed that all 22 227 rows are returned. Some of them should get filtered out.

Comment: in theory. if you run the inner query returning table [t1] should bring the 22227 rows with an added column (noac) , then the wrapper that returns [t] should filter the rows  with the where clause [noac] < [asm] so as pointed out by @VladimirBaranov the problem could be the Null values in [acid]. He's made an enhancement to the dense rank trick to work with nulls too.