# How to aggregate (counting distinct items) over a sliding window in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, aggregate-functions, sliding-window

I am currently using this query (in SQL Server) to count the number of unique item each day:

```
SELECT Date, COUNT(DISTINCT item) 
FROM myTable 
GROUP BY Date 
ORDER BY Date
```

How can I transform this to get for each date **the number of unique item over the past 3 days** (including the current day)?

The output should be a table with 2 columns:
one columns with all dates in the original table. On the second column, we have the number of unique item per date.

for instance if original table is:

```
Date        Item  
01/01/2018  A  
01/01/2018  B  
02/01/2018  C  
03/01/2018  C    
04/01/2018  C
```

With my query above I currently get the unique count for each day:

```
Date        count  
01/01/2018  2  
02/01/2018  1  
03/01/2018  1  
04/01/2018  1
```

and I am looking to get as result the unique count over 3 days rolling window:

```
Date        count  
01/01/2018  2  
02/01/2018  3  (because items ABC on 1st and 2nd Jan)
03/01/2018  3  (because items ABC on 1st,2nd,3rd Jan)    
04/01/2018  1  (because only item C on 2nd,3rd,4th Jan)
```

Answer (score 8):

Using an `apply` provides a convenient way to form sliding windows

```
CREATE TABLE myTable 
    ([DateCol] datetime, [Item] varchar(1))
;

INSERT INTO myTable 
    ([DateCol], [Item])
VALUES
    ('2018-01-01 00:00:00', 'A'),
    ('2018-01-01 00:00:00', 'B'),
    ('2018-01-02 00:00:00', 'C'),
    ('2018-01-03 00:00:00', 'C'),
    ('2018-01-04 00:00:00', 'C')
;

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_DateCol  
    ON MyTable([Date])  
;
```

**Query**:

```
select distinct 
       t1.dateCol
     , oa.ItemCount
from myTable t1
outer apply (
      select count(distinct t2.item) as ItemCount
      from myTable t2
      where t2.DateCol between dateadd(day,-2,t1.DateCol) and t1.DateCol
  ) oa
order by t1.dateCol ASC
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9cff4/1/0)**:

```
|              dateCol | ItemCount |
|----------------------|-----------|
| 2018-01-01T00:00:00Z |         2 |
| 2018-01-02T00:00:00Z |         3 |
| 2018-01-03T00:00:00Z |         3 |
| 2018-01-04T00:00:00Z |         1 |
```

There may be some performance gains by reducing the `date` column prior to using the `apply`, like so:

```
select 
       d.date
     , oa.ItemCount
from (
    select distinct t1.date
    from myTable t1
     ) d
outer apply (
      select count(distinct t2.item) as ItemCount
      from myTable t2
      where t2.Date between dateadd(day,-2,d.Date) and d.Date
  ) oa
order by d.date ASC
;
```

Instead of using `select distinct` in that subquery you could use `group by` instead but the execution plan will remain the same.

[Demo at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/9cff4/1)

Comment: Thank you. It seems however very slow. Could we instead imagine to join 3 tables, each with a different lag, and run the usual count distinct on the joined table?

Comment: Do you have an index on the `DateCol`? Have you looked at the execution plan?

Comment: Cross apply will work faster. In any case @RockScience, apply works greatly faster than using LAG in any case. You can experiment yourself on that and read numerous relevant articles. To give you an example, in a similar case of yours, in my production database that is ~15m rows, using apply runs in 5mins and using LAG takes 3 hours.

Answer (score 5):

The most straight forward solution is to join the table with itself based on dates:

```
SELECT t1.DateCol, COUNT(DISTINCT t2.Item) AS C
FROM testdata AS t1 
LEFT JOIN testdata AS t2 ON t2.DateCol BETWEEN DATEADD(dd, -2, t1.DateCol) AND t1.DateCol
GROUP BY t1.DateCol
ORDER BY t1.DateCol
```

Output:

```
| DateCol                 | C |
|-------------------------|---|
| 2018-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 2 |
| 2018-01-02 00:00:00.000 | 3 |
| 2018-01-03 00:00:00.000 | 3 |
| 2018-01-04 00:00:00.000 | 1 |
```

Answer (score 3):

`GROUP BY` should be faster then `DISTINCT` (make sure to have an index on your `Date` column)

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE([Date] DATE, [Item] VARCHAR(100))
;

INSERT INTO @tbl  VALUES
    ('2018-01-01 00:00:00', 'A'),
    ('2018-01-01 00:00:00', 'B'),
    ('2018-01-02 00:00:00', 'C'),
    ('2018-01-03 00:00:00', 'C'),
    ('2018-01-04 00:00:00', 'C');

SELECT t.[Date]

      --Just for control. You can take this part away
      ,(SELECT DISTINCT t2.[Item] AS [*]
        FROM @tbl AS t2
        WHERE t2.[Date]<=t.[Date] 
          AND t2.[Date]>=DATEADD(DAY,-2,t.[Date]) FOR XML PATH('')) AS CountedItems

      --This sub-select comes back with your counts 
      ,(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT t2.[Item])
        FROM @tbl AS t2
        WHERE t2.[Date]<=t.[Date] 
          AND t2.[Date]>=DATEADD(DAY,-2,t.[Date])) AS ItemCount
FROM @tbl AS t
GROUP BY t.[Date];
```

The result

```
Date        CountedItems    ItemCount
2018-01-01  AB              2
2018-01-02  ABC             3
2018-01-03  ABC             3
2018-01-04  C               1
```

Answer (score 2):

This solution is different from other solutions. Can you check performance of this query on real data with comparison to other answers?

The basic idea is that each row can participate in the window for its own date, the day after, or the day after that. So this first expands the row out into three rows with those different dates attached and then it can just use a regular `COUNT(DISTINCT)` aggregating on the computed date. The `HAVING` clause is just to avoid returning results for dates that were solely computed and not present in the base data.

```
with cte(Date, Item) as (
    select cast(a as datetime), b 
    from (values 
        ('01/01/2018','A')
        ,('01/01/2018','B')
        ,('02/01/2018','C')
        ,('03/01/2018','C')
        ,('04/01/2018','C')) t(a,b)
)

select 
    [Date] = dateadd(dd, n, Date), [Count] = count(distinct Item)
from 
    cte
    cross join (values (0),(1),(2)) t(n)
group by dateadd(dd, n, Date)
having max(iif(n = 0, 1, 0)) = 1

option (force order)
```

Output:

```
|        Date             | Count |
|-------------------------|-------|
| 2018-01-01 00:00:00.000 |   2   |
| 2018-01-02 00:00:00.000 |   3   |
| 2018-01-03 00:00:00.000 |   3   |
| 2018-01-04 00:00:00.000 |   1   |
```

It might be faster if you have many duplicate rows:

```
select 
    [Date] = dateadd(dd, n, Date), [Count] = count(distinct Item)
from 
    (select distinct Date, Item from cte) c
    cross join (values (0),(1),(2)) t(n)
group by dateadd(dd, n, Date)
having max(iif(n = 0, 1, 0)) = 1

option (force order)
```

Comment: thank you. could you clarify the command I should run, assuming that my table is named myTable ? For now I get error ` SQL Server Database Error: "a" is not a recognized table hints option. If it is intended as a parameter to a table-valued function or to the CHANGETABLE function, ensure that your database compatibility mode is set to 90.`

Comment: In the query above I have used common table expression as your table and filled with sample data. This is not neccessary for you. So, you must run the part that begins with `SELECT` statement and change `cte` with `myTable`. And what is your SQL Server version?

Comment: And many thanks to @Martin Smith for adding description to my query

Comment: Using cross apply is faster than using cross join,so in cases like that where you don't really want to join data from different tables, change cross join with cross apply

Answer (score 1):

Use `GETDATE()` function to get current date, and `DATEADD()` to get the last 3 days

```
 SELECT Date, count(DISTINCT item) 
 FROM myTable 
 WHERE [Date] >= DATEADD(day,-3, GETDATE())
 GROUP BY Date 
 ORDER BY Date
```

Comment: Thank you, that gives me one point. I am looking to get this for each date.

Comment: sorry what is wrong with my answer? can you post some sample data and what result you need?

Comment: 1) what is 'day' in your query? 2) added example in question.I don't want the last 3 days. I want for each date the unique items over rolling 3 days

Comment: Day is  the units you want add or substract, can be months, years. But looks like after adding the sample data and the bounty you are getting better answer now.

Answer (score 1):

#### SQL

```
SELECT DISTINCT Date,
       (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT item)
        FROM myTable t2
        WHERE t2.Date BETWEEN DATEADD(day, -2, t1.Date) AND t1.Date) AS count
FROM myTable t1
ORDER BY Date;
```

#### Demo

Rextester demo: http://rextester.com/ZRDQ22190

Answer (score 1):

Since `COUNT(DISTINCT item) OVER (PARTITION BY [Date])` is not supported you can use `dense_rank` to emulate that:

```
SELECT Date, dense_rank() over (partition by [Date] order by [item]) 
+ dense_rank() over (partition by [Date] order by [item] desc) 
- 1 as count_distinct_item
FROM myTable
```

One thing to note is that `dense_rank` will count null as whereas `COUNT` will not.

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11202878/partition-function-count-over-possible-using-distinct) post for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution that uses myTable itself as the source of grouping dates (edited for SQLServer dateadd). Note that this query assumes there will be at least one record in myTable for every date; if any date is absent, it will not appear in the query results, even if there are records for the 2 days prior:

```
select
    date,
    (select
        count(distinct item)
        from (select distinct date, item from myTable) as d2
     where
        d2.date between dateadd(day,-2,d.date) and d.date
    ) as count
from (select distinct date from myTable) as d
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve this question with Math.

z (any day) = 3x + y  (y is mode 3 value)
I need from 3 * (x - 1) + y + 1 to 3 * (x - 1) + y + 3

3 * (x- 1) + y + 1 = 3* (z / 3 - 1) + z % 3 + 1

In that case; I can use group by (between 3* (z / 3 - 1) + z % 3 + 1  and z)

```
    SELECT  iif(OrderDate between  3 * (cast(OrderDate as int) / 3 - 1) + (cast(OrderDate as int) % 3) + 1 
and orderdate, Orderdate, 0)
, count(sh.SalesOrderID) FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail shd
JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader sh on sh.SalesOrderID = shd.SalesOrderID
group by iif(OrderDate between  3 * (cast(OrderDate as int) / 3 - 1) + (cast(OrderDate as int) % 3) + 1 
and orderdate, Orderdate, 0)
order by iif(OrderDate between  3 * (cast(OrderDate as int) / 3 - 1) + (cast(OrderDate as int) % 3) + 1 
and orderdate, Orderdate, 0)
```

If you need else day group, you can use;

```
declare @n int = 4 (another day count)

SELECT  iif(OrderDate between  @n * (cast(OrderDate as int) / @n - 1) + (cast(OrderDate as int) % @n) + 1 
and orderdate, Orderdate, 0)
, count(sh.SalesOrderID) FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail shd
JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader sh on sh.SalesOrderID = shd.SalesOrderID
group by iif(OrderDate between  @n * (cast(OrderDate as int) / @n - 1) + (cast(OrderDate as int) % @n) + 1 
and orderdate, Orderdate, 0)
order by iif(OrderDate between  @n * (cast(OrderDate as int) / @n - 1) + (cast(OrderDate as int) % @n) + 1 
and orderdate, Orderdate, 0)
```