# How to count the number of records in an sql database

Tags: sql, count

I am using the below query to get distinct records from 4 specific columns in an sql DB.

```
SELECT DISTINCT customer,
       product,
       category,
       sector
FROM data_table
```

I need to add the count of products in this query. Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean `count of products`? What database are you using? In databases with window functions you could use `OVER(*)` with `COUNT()` or `DENSE_RANK()` [like these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11202878/partition-function-count-over-possible-using-distinct) to perform the equivalent of `COUNT(DISTINCT product)`. If you want the overall totall, `COUNT(*) OVER()` or `OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) `

Comment: Can you please show sample data and expected results? As it stands, it's hard to answer your question...Please also specify the specific RDBMS you're using.

Comment: @HarrisVrachimis . . . What do *you* mean by "add the count of products in this query"?  It is not at all clear what the result set would look like.

Answer (score 2):

are you find something below

```
select count(*) from
(SELECT DISTINCT customer, product, category, sector 
FROM data_table
) a
```

or do you need window function count() if your dbms support

```
SELECT DISTINCT customer, product, category, sector,
count(*) over()  as cnt
FROM data_table
```