# How to do a COUNT(DISTINCT) using window functions with a frame in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, window-functions, dense-rank

Piggybacking this lovely question:
[Partition Function COUNT() OVER possible using DISTINCT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11202878/partition-function-count-over-possible-using-distinct)

I wish to calculate a moving count of distinct value.
Something along the lines of:

`Count(distinct machine_id) over(partition by model order by _timestamp rows between 6 preceding and current row)`

Obviously, SQL Server does not support the syntax. Unfortunately, I don't understand well enough (didn't internalize would be more accurate) how that dense_rank walk-around works:

```
dense_rank() over (partition by model order by machine_id) 
+ dense_rank() over (partition by model order by machine_id) 
- 1
```

and therefore I am not able tweak it to meet my need for a moving window.
If I order by machine_id, would it be enough to order by _timestamp as well and use `rows between`?

Comment: Tried `dense_rank() over (partition by model order by _timestamp, machine_id rows between CURRENT ROW and 6 following) 
+ dense_rank() over (partition by model order by _timestamp, machine_id rows between CURRENT ROW and 6 following) 
- 1` but to no avail:
 "The function 'dense_rank' may not have a window frame."

:-(

Comment: Sample data and expected output will be helpful. There might be an easier way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`dense_rank()` gives the dense ranking of the the current record. When you run that with `ASC` sort order first, you get the current record's dense rank (unique value rank) from the first element. When you run with `DESC` order, then you get the current record's dense rank from the last record. Then you remove 1 because the dense ranking of the current record is counted twice. This gives the total unique values in the whole partition (and repeated for every row).

Since, `dense_rank` does not support `frames`, you can't use this solution directly. You need to generate the `frame` by other means. One way could be `JOIN`ing the same table with proper `unique id` comparisons. Then, you can use `dense_rank` on the combined version.

Please check out the following solution proposal. The assumption there is you have a unique record key (`record_id`) available in your table. If you don't have a unique key, add another CTE before the first CTE and generate a unique key for each record (using `new_id()` function OR combining multiple columns using `concat()` with delimiter in between to account for `NULLs`)

```
; WITH cte AS (
SELECT 
  record_id
  , record_id_6_record_earlier = LEAD(machine_id, 6, NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY model ORDER BY _timestamp)
  , .... other columns
FROM mainTable
)
, cte2 AS (
SELECT 
  c.*
  , DistinctCntWithin6PriorRec = dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY c.model, c.record_id ORDER BY t._timestamp)
    + dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY c.model, c.record_id ORDER BY t._timestamp DESC)
    - 1
  , RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.record_id ORDER BY t._timestamp )
FROM cte c
     LEFT JOIN mainTable t ON t.record_id BETWEEN c.record_id_6_record_earlier  and c.record_id
)
SELECT *
FROM cte2
WHERE RN = 1
```

There are 2 LIMITATIONS of this solution:

1. If the frame has less than 6 records, then the `LAG()` function will be `NULL` and thus this solution will not work. This can be handled in different ways: One quick way I can think of is to generate 6 LEAD columns (1 record prior, 2 records prior, etc.) and then change the `BETWEEN` clause to something like this `BETWEEN COALESCE(c.record_id_6_record_earlier, c.record_id_5_record_earlier, ...., c.record_id_1_record_earlier, c.record_id)  and c.record_id`
2. `COUNT()` does not count `NULL`. But `DENSE_RANK` does. You need account for that too if it applies to your data

Answer (score 4):

Just use `outer apply`:

```
select t.*, t2.num_machines
from t outer apply
     (select count(distinct t2.machine_id) as num_machines
      from (select top (6) t2.*
            from t t2
            where t2.model = t.model and
                  t2.timestamp <= t.timestamp
            order by t2.timestamp desc
           ) t2
      ) t2;
```

If you have a lot of rows per model, you can also use a (cumbersome) trick using `lag()`:

```
select t.*, v.num_machines
from (select t.*,
             lag(machine_id, 1) over (partition by model order by timestamp) as machine_id_1,
             lag(machine_id, 2) over (partition by model order by timestamp) as machine_id_2,
             lag(machine_id, 3) over (partition by model order by timestamp) as machine_id_3,
             lag(machine_id, 4) over (partition by model order by timestamp) as machine_id_4,
             lag(machine_id, 5) over (partition by model order by timestamp) as machine_id_5
      from t
     ) t cross apply
     (select count(distinct v.machine_id) as num_machines
      from (values (t.machine_id),
                   (t.machine_id_1),
                   (t.machine_id_2),
                   (t.machine_id_3),
                   (t.machine_id_4),
                   (t.machine_id_5)
           ) v(machine_id)
      ) v;
```

Under many circumstances, this might have the best performance in SQL Server.