# Select the duplicate rows with specific values

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I only get the data with the same `ID`, but not the same `Name`?

The following is the example to explain my thought. Thanks.

```
ID     Name     Date          
123    Amy     08/03/2022   
123    Amy     12/03/2022    
456    Billy   08/03/2022    
456    Cat     09/03/2022    
789    Peter   10/03/2022
```

Expected Output:

```
ID     Name     Date
456    Billy   08/03/2022    
456    Cat     09/03/2022
```

How I have done.

```
select ID, Name, count(*)
from table
groupby ID, Name
having count(*) > 1
```

But the result included the following parts that I do not want it.

```
ID     Name     Date          
123    Amy     08/03/2022   
123    Amy     12/03/2022
```

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach would be to use a subquery to identify `ID`s that have multiple names.

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM YourTable GROUP BY ID HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Name) > 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE ID = 456;
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE ID IN
  (SELECT 
     ID
   FROM table_name
   GROUP BY ID
   HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT name) > 1
  );
```

?

Comment: Your subquery should only return the id column. (As it is now, you'll get an error.)

Comment: And the HAVING clause condition should be `> 1`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd join the table to its self like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.Id as ID_A,
    b.Id as ID_B,
    a.[Name] as Name_A
FROM
    Test as a
INNER JOIN Test as b
    ON A.Id = B.Id
WHERE
    A.[Name] <> B.[Name]
```

[image]

Comment: What will happen if there's a 3rd row with id = 456?

Comment: @jarlh you'd probably want to get the distinct to filter those down.

Comment: `DISTINCT` doesn't change this query, you'll still end up with every combination or n * (n-1) rows.

Answer (score 0):

**Window functions are likely to be the most efficient here.** They do not require self-joining of the source table.

Unfortunately, SQL Server does not support `COUNT(DISTINCT` as a window function. But we can simulate it by using `DENSE_RANK` and `MAX`

```sql
WITH DistinctRanks AS (
    SELECT *,
      rnk = DENSE_RANK(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Name)
    FROM YourTable
),
MaxRanks AS (
    SELECT *,
      mr = MAX(rnk) OVER (PARTITION BY ID)
    FROM DistinctRanks
)
SELECT
  ID,
  Name,
  Count
FROM MaxRanks t
WHERE t.mr > 1;
```

Comment: This query identifies IDs that exist more than once, it doesn't take into account the OPs name requirement. Unfortunately it can't be fixed using `DISTINCT`, you can use `DENSE_RANK` though. https://stackoverflow.com/a/22347502/3194005

Comment: Righto, missed that, have modified. Hey that's funny, you edited your comment the exact same time I changed the query, although I had a different solution