# Finding MAX rank when using DENSE_RANK to achieve incremental ranking

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

Setup

```sql
go
create table eidmadm.PerfData1 (id int primary key, c1 varchar(100))
create table eidmadm.PerfData2 (id int identity primary key, fkId int, c1 varchar(100), FOREIGN KEY (fkId) REFERENCES eidmadm.PerfData1(id))

go

DECLARE @id INTEGER = 0;


begin 
    WHILE @id <= 10000
    BEGIN

        SET @id = @id + 1; 

        insert into eidmadm.PerfData1 (id, c1) values (@id, concat( 'item ', @id) );
        
        if @id % 2 = 0
        begin
            insert into eidmadm.PerfData2 (fkId, c1) values (@id, concat( 'SubItem ', @id, '-', 1) );
            insert into eidmadm.PerfData2 (fkId, c1) values (@id, concat( 'SubItem ', @id, '-', 2) );
            insert into eidmadm.PerfData2 (fkId, c1) values (@id, concat( 'SubItem ', @id, '-', 3) );
        end;

    END;

end;

go
```

Here is my query

```
SELECT
    Union_Tbl_Alias.*,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id) toprow,
    --RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id, subitem desc) AS Rank  
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS Rank
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        eidmadm.PerfData1.id,
        eidmadm.PerfData1.c1 item,
        eidmadm.PerfData2.c1 subitem--,
    FROM 
        eidmadm.PerfData1 inner join 
        eidmadm.PerfData2 on eidmadm.PerfData1.id = eidmadm.PerfData2.fkId
    WHERE (1 = 1) 

    UNION

    SELECT 
        eidmadm.PerfData1.id,
        eidmadm.PerfData1.c1 item,
        eidmadm.PerfData2.c1 subitem--,
    FROM 
        eidmadm.PerfData1 left join 
        eidmadm.PerfData2 on eidmadm.PerfData1.id = eidmadm.PerfData2.fkId
    WHERE (1 = 1) and eidmadm.PerfData2.fkId is NULL

) Union_Tbl_Alias
ORDER BY
    id, subitem desc
OFFSET 0 ROWS    
FETCH NEXT 5000 ROWS ONLY
```

The Resultset is looking good

| id | item | subitem | toprow | Rank |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | item 1 | NULL | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | item 2 | SubItem 2-3 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | item 2 | SubItem 2-2 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | item 2 | SubItem 2-1 | 3 | 2 |
| 3 | item 3 | NULL | 1 | 3 |
| 4 | item 4 | SubItem 4-3 | 1 | 4 |
| 4 | item 4 | SubItem 4-2 | 2 | 4 |
| 4 | item 4 | SubItem 4-1 | 3 | 4 |
| 5 | item 5 | NULL | 1 | 5 |
| 6 | item 6 | SubItem 6-3 | 1 | 6 |

Is it possible to find what is the lowest rank without doing `GROUP BY`? I am OK if this query becomes inline view in the wrapping query.

Comment: Just use `DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY id)` instead of `RANK()`

Comment: @GMB phew... so much work for this :-)

Comment: @GMB With this said, is there a way also to retrieve the MAX rank in the same query? Sort of like - look ahead. Or at least if this query becomes inline view then in the wrapping query??

Comment: Maybe you want `COUNT(*) OVER()`? That gives you the total count of records. It's pretty close to *the max of `RANK`*, but differs if there are ties in last position.

Comment: @GMB I've been adding `COUNT(*) OVER()`. I will have to compare tomorrow the difference of count with `rank`. In my case 1 record will not make much difference. Thanks

Comment: @GMB I reformatted my question since the original was an easy answer. And now I realized that I can't get close to the actualy number I need using `COUNT(*) OVER()` etc. FYI. Thanks

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11202878/partition-function-count-over-possible-using-distinct help? Maybe `dense_rank() over (ORDER BY id) + dense_rank() over (ORDER BY id desc)  - 1`?

Comment: @EdmCoff This is interesting!! this returns me total number of ranks. True. But then I take 5000. And I need to find Max at this cut out. I am going to try additional layer of inline view. Work in Progress

Comment: @EdmCoff I found the way and posted the answer. Your approach worked but it can be done by using `MAX(Rank) OVER ()`. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the SQL that achieves exactly what I want

```sql
SELECT
    outer_table.*,
    /* additional subquery-based columns*/
FROM
(
    SELECT
        rank_table.*
        ,MAX(Rank) OVER () AS sys___MAX_RANK
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            Union_Tbl_Alias.*
            ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY id desc) AS Rank
        FROM
        (
            SELECT 
                eidmadm.PerfData1.id,
                eidmadm.PerfData1.c1 item,
                eidmadm.PerfData2.c1 subitem--,
            FROM 
                eidmadm.PerfData1 inner join 
                eidmadm.PerfData2 on eidmadm.PerfData1.id = eidmadm.PerfData2.fkId
            WHERE (1 = 1) 

            UNION

            SELECT 
                eidmadm.PerfData1.id,
                eidmadm.PerfData1.c1 item,
                eidmadm.PerfData2.c1 subitem--,
            FROM 
                eidmadm.PerfData1 left join 
                eidmadm.PerfData2 on eidmadm.PerfData1.id = eidmadm.PerfData2.fkId
            WHERE (1 = 1) and eidmadm.PerfData2.fkId is NULL

        ) Union_Tbl_Alias
        ORDER BY
            id desc, subitem desc
        OFFSET 0 ROWS    -- required here 
        FETCH NEXT 5000 ROWS ONLY 
    ) rank_table
) outer_table    
where outer_table.Rank between 1 and 25
order by outer_table.Rank
```

`DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY id desc) AS Rank` in `rank_table` gets me the ranking over 5000 rows. And based on data this rank value will usually be less then 5000. `MAX(Rank) OVER () AS sys___MAX_RANK` gets me that number (max rank over number of records in `fetch`). Then in the `outer_table` I can simply get my page of data based on the `rank` and sort it by the rank, which efficient.

Basically, the motivation here is to achieve paging based on rank and not consecutive rows. I need to collate some of the values in the query, hence `GROUP BY` is not really possible. But if anyone has a better way, welcome to provide the answer.