How to find records which are present in multiple groups
Below is my scenario



Column A
Column B




Group-A
1


Group-A
2


Group-A
1


Group-A
1


Group-B
3


Group-B
1


Group-B
5


Group-B
3



I need to Flag value 1 from Column-B as it is present in multiple group (Group-A and Group-B). Also value 5 present twice in Group-B is fine as it is not present in multiple Group.
I am expecting below Result:



Column A
Column B




Group-A
1


Group-B
1



Any help either on sql or presto would work for me.

What does Also value 5 present twice in Group-B is fine as it is not present in multiple Group mean? (Your expected result doesn't contain any value 5.)

Note that tables have rows, not records.

Would be neat if windows functions supported count distinct, but they don't. One method is using a subquery.
select distinct colA, colB
from table1
where colB in (
 select colB
 from table1
 group by colB
 having count(distinct colA) > 1
);




colA
colB




Group-A
1


Group-B
1



fiddle

The DENSE_RANK fiddle gets COUNT(DISTINCT) with Window functions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11202878/partition-function-count-over-possible-using-distinct

I would use an IN clause in this case and check there are different values in column A for the value in column B:
SELECT DISTINCT a, b
FROM yourtable y
WHERE b IN
  (SELECT b
  FROM yourtable y2 WHERE y.a <> y2.a);

Result for your sample data:



a
b




Group-A
1


Group-B
1



fiddle

Using SQL would be like this:
-- create table
CREATE TABLE Test (
  "Column A" varchar(100),
  "Column B" int
);

-- insert values
INSERT INTO Test ("Column A", "Column B")
VALUES ("Group-A", 1);

INSERT INTO Test ("Column A", "Column B")
VALUES ("Group-A", 2);

INSERT INTO Test ("Column A", "Column B")
VALUES ("Group-A", 1);

INSERT INTO Test ("Column A", "Column B")
VALUES ("Group-A", 1);

INSERT INTO Test ("Column A", "Column B")
VALUES ("Group-B", 3);

INSERT INTO Test ("Column A", "Column B")
VALUES ("Group-B", 1);

INSERT INTO Test ("Column A", "Column B")
VALUES ("Group-B", 5);

INSERT INTO Test ("Column A", "Column B")
VALUES ("Group-B", 3);

-- query
SELECT DISTINCT t1."Column A", t1."Column B"
FROM Test t1
WHERE t1."Column B" IN (
    SELECT "Column B"
    FROM Test
    GROUP BY "Column B"
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT "Column A") > 1
);


Where's the difference to this answer?

@JonasMetzler, a big difference is that this one doesn't work on SQL Server. (Using double quotes for string literals isn't valid SQL Server syntax. Perhaps Presto?)

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

@jarlh Oh, sorry, I'm used to write PL-SQL as generic and it could be re-writen in any other SQL... I worked with SQL Server for 3 years and it is not difficult to re-write it... I haven't used Presto in my whole life. As this question is tagged as SQL then I thought he could use an engine like PostgreSQL, MySQL, etc... I tested this one in an online sql compiler as I was in a hurry on a release and was using my Idea IDE to code fixes if a bug came up. https://www.programiz.com/sql/online-compiler/

@JonasMetzler none, I started asnwering it when I saw it had no answers. I wrote all the create and inserts because the question seems to come from someone that might not be used to use SQL.

Use window functions. Return a row if the ColumnB value's rows have different ColumnA values.
SELECT DISTINCT a, b
FROM (
  select a, b,
        max(a) over (partition by b) max_a,
        min(a) over (partition by b) min_a
  from yourtable
) y
where max_a <> min_a

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/83NS_UQF (based on @Jonas Metzler's, thanks!)
